# jenkins shell command change dir fail

Tags: linux, jenkins

I have this weierd problem with executing a simple shell in jenkins.

when I try to "cd" to a folder I get this:

```
+ cd /var/www/LPSv1
/tmp/hudson152852774815841559.sh: 8: cd: can't cd to /var/www/LPSv1
```

the bash that was used is simply

```
cd /var/www/LPSv1
```

this gives me an error,
but when I'm logged as "jenkins" user in the terminal, I get no problem...